# Configure dns server for domain name without prefix

Tags: domain-name-system, local-area-network

Trying to set up a local dns server as to speed up intranet development.

I use bind9 set a sub domain named mydomain.com with /etc/bind/db.mydomain.com.

The problem is that I can correctly resolve address like server.mydomain.com, but the server can not resolve mydomain.com (which without the prefix).

Is there anything I missed?

( My configuration is kind similar as this article http://www.geoffke.be/nieuws/8/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not figure out how to configure under bind9.

But solved this problem using the dnsmasq service.

So, I removed both bind9 and udhcpd service, instead of using [dnsmasq](http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq) as dhcp and dns service provider. In dnsmasq, it will search local /etc/hosts file first where I simply put whatever domain name I want to cheat lan clients.

Answer (score 1):

Typically sub-domains are a different and seperate forward lookup zone.  If you want to make the entire domain searchable you either need a forward lookup zone for each domain (mydomain.com, db.mydomain.com, etc.)

Or simply create a forward lookup zone for mydomain.com and add A records for db.mydomain.com as well.  If you need more than just A and CNAME records you will need a different forward lookup zone for each domain.

Answer (score 1):

looking at the tutorial you used, i see the following:

```
; IP addresses of local hosts (replace the lines with your own hosts): 
router             IN     A     192.168.1.1 
ns1                IN     A     192.168.1.2 
www                IN     A     192.168.1.3 
mediacenter        IN     A     192.168.1.4 
laptop1            IN     A     192.168.1.5 
workstation1       IN     A     192.168.1.6
```

you established A-records for a bunch of subdomains, but none for your TLD. just add a A-record without defining a subdomain like this:

```
; IP addresses of local hosts (replace the lines with your own hosts): 
                   IN     A     192.168.1.100
router             IN     A     192.168.1.1 
ns1                IN     A     192.168.1.2 
www                IN     A     192.168.1.3 
mediacenter        IN     A     192.168.1.4 
laptop1            IN     A     192.168.1.5 
workstation1       IN     A     192.168.1.6
```

where *192.168.1.100* is the IP you want to point to and you're set.

Comment: Tried, but seems does not work.

Comment: it's best you'd post your zone file, else it's just guesswork for me